# Why am I getting 'borrow of moved value here' error after using dbg!()?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have this code, but its giving me an error I don't understand:

```rust
fn main() {
    // --snip--

    let mut unit = String::new();

    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut unit)
        .expect("couldn't read line!");

    let unit = unit.trim().to_lowercase();
    dbg!(unit);

    if unit == "f" {
        println!("temperature in Celsius is : {}°c", f_to_c(temp));
    } else if unit == "c" {
        println!("temperature in Fahrenheit is : {}°f", c_to_f(temp));
    } else {
        println!("'{unit}' unit not supported!");
    }
}
```

```
error[E0382]: borrow of moved value: `unit`
  --> src/lib.rs:16:8
   |
13 |     let unit = unit.trim().to_lowercase();
   |         ---- move occurs because `unit` has type `String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
14 |     dbg!(unit);
   |     ---------- value moved here
15 |
16 |     if unit == "f" {
   |        ^^^^ value borrowed here after move
```

I made `unit` explicitly type `String` but that wasn't the cause. How is this error is generated?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `dbg!` macro moves its arguments.
You can use it and not consume the argument by passing only a reference like this:

```rust
dbg!(&unit);
```

instead.